# SQL query to compare closest date

Tags: sql-server, max, subquery

I'm trying to select one location for each transaction row.

The problem is that the client can transfer to different locations.  I've been successful in selecting MAX(ClientLocation.TransferDate), but I don't need that date.  That date is my only way to compare what location the client was at when the transaction took place.

I keep getting results where each transaction is duplicated based on the number of ClientLocation.Location they have.

```
SELECT MAX(ClientLocation.TransferDate, Transaction.Date, Client.Name, Location.Name
FROM Transaction
JOIN Client ON Transaction.ClientID = Client.ID
JOIN ClientLocation ON Client.ID = ClientLocation.ClientID 
JOIN Location ON ClientLocation.LocationID = Location.ID
WHERE Client.ID=ClientLocation.ClientID < Transaction.Date
GROUP BY Transaction.Date, Client.Name, Location.Name
```

Comment: Can you provide the DDL for the Client, ClientLocation, Location and Transaction tables? Some sample data and the outputs you expect from querying same would also help.

Answer (score 1):

I've just been trying to prototype your issue out. Part of the problem is that your SQL as it stands isn't a valid SQL DML statement. Problems include your 'MAX(...' aggregator column not having a closing bracket, your 'Transaction' table using a reserved keyword as its name, and your WHERE clause being invalid (it includes multiple operators that don't work together).

Try this for starters:

```
SELECT MAX(t.TransferDate), t.Date, c.Name, l.Name
FROM [Transaction] t JOIN Client c ON t.ClientID = c.ID
JOIN ClientLocation cl ON c.ID = cl.ClientID 
JOIN Location l ON cl.LocationID = l.ID
WHERE c.ID = cl.ClientID 
GROUP BY t.Date, c.Name, l.Name
```

It at least compiles, though it's still unclear what you're actually trying to do. I suspect, however, that at least part of your problem is that there's nothing in your Transactions table that indicates which ClientLocation a given transaction is associated with. So, trying to group by that factor later on isn't going to be possible, unless you change your schema.